# PyCharm shows error with input() function

Tags: python, python-2.7, pycharm

I am trying to execute following code:

```
x = input('hello')
print (x)
```

[image]

But this code works on the command line:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using Python 2.7, it's better to use [`raw_input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) instead of `input()`, as the latter tries to determine the type of the input and convert it automatically. `raw_input()` will always return a string.

```
x = raw_input('hello ')
print (x)
```

As @Darius pointed out, if you leave it the way you wrote it, and type `"dfd"` in the console instead of `dfd`, it will work. But `raw_input()` is the safe and proper method in Python 2.x.

Comment: Alternatively you type `"hello"` in the console.

Comment: You're right, noted! :)

Comment: It worked!!! thanks will and also Darius

Comment: No problem, glad to help! :)